# CreatedAt,UpdatedAt not working after Azure,mobile service .Net backend database migration

Tags: ios, .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

We created a new schema and database to use an existing schema in a .Net Azure mobile service backend, so we used migration to do that. After the migration creates the new schema successfully, we populated data to test our IOS app.

Right now,I am facing a trouble having the CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,version update through the IOS native app keeps being null. When we do a use post,patch request from mobile service page, it does write values into these fields without a problem.
 The migration created the Id as a primary key, and CreatedAt, UpdatedAt is a datetimeoffest. The CreatedAt is an implementation of the ITableData with a default getter and setter like public datetimeoffset CreatedAt{get;set;}

If it is a blackened issue then how can I fix it?

Comment: Normally, Db Entity should be derived from "EntityData" than "ITableData". When we use "EntityData", the framework will generate corresponding triggers to populate createdat and updatedat fields. you don't need to do it explicitly. In order to check this one, download a sample azure mobile service, run and check the trigger part of any table.

Comment: You can't set CreatedAt and UpdatedAt directly from your client--the server values will be used instead. Are you instead talking about reading the values?  To read system properties, you need to request them from your client -- see http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-services/iOS/v2/Classes/MSTable.html#//api/name/systemProperties